# How to extract data values and added to tableview

Tags: objective-c, json, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

How to extract the data from the below data structure, and display on tableview

```
id = extractData
[extractData objectForKey:@"data"] //BELOW IS OUTPUT:

 ( {
       Name =  {
            id = 2;
            name = rat;
        };
        Place =  {
            id = 7;
            name = New York;
        };
        Item =   {
            Times = "100";
            “expire” = 10-19-2015;
            “value” = 300;
            id = 1;
            name = newname;
            “checked” = 0;
        };
        Type =  {
            id = 1;
            name = round;
        };
    },
        {
        Name =  {
            id = 2;
            name = norway;
        };
        Place =   {
            id = 3;
            name = ops;
        };
        Item =  {
            Times = "100";
            “expire” = 10-18-2015;
            “value” = 300;
            id = 1;
            name = new;
            “checked” = 1;
        };
        Type =         {
            id = 2;
            name = square;
        };
    }
)
```

Want to display Name,Place,Item,Type values in tableview cell with each iterations. 
Can any one advice, how can extract value from above data.

Comment: There are easily a hundred examples here on SO, and several hundred more elsewhere on the Internet.  Do some homework.

Comment: One hint.  When you NSLog an NSArray it comes out with elements enclosed in `()` and separated by commas.  When you NSLog an NSDictionary it comes out with its elements enclosed in `{}` and separated by `;`, with the key/value pairs separated by `=`.  That should be enough info for you to read the above dump and process it.

Comment: @HotLicks  above is Array of Dictionary!!!

Comment: You got it!  So work it out from there.  (Do note that the dictionaries contain more dictionaries.)

Comment: Thanks for the info, [[extractData objectForKey:@"data"] count]  gives the count extract value example:[[[[extractData objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Place"] objectForKey:@"name"]);

Comment: Except be very wary of writing "long chain polymer" code like that.  Do each step on a separate line and assign to a temp.  Then you can debug it.

Comment: @HotLicks you are correct...!!! I do that.

Comment: If you haven't already done so, compare the above NSLog representation to the source JSON.  They are very similar, only JSON uses `[]` instead of `()`, `:` instead of `=`, slightly different punctuation, and quotes all string literals rather than just some.  And, of course, go to json.org and study the JSON syntax.  Then it will make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Under your cellForRowAtIndexPath after initializing the custom cell add this code :

```
NSDictionary *dicVal = [yourDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.labelName.text = [[dicVal objectForKey:@"Name"] objectForKey:@"name"];
cell.labelPlace.text = [[dicVal objectForKey:@"Place"] objectForKey:@"name"];
cell.labelItem.text = [[dicVal objectForKey:@"Item"] objectForKey:@"name"];
cell.labelType.text = [[dicVal objectForKey:@"Type"] objectForKey:@"name"];

return yourCustomCell;
```

This should do the work. Thanks.